# How to set CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE on a customized listView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a customized ListView like this:

```
List<Journal_Database> values = localDatabase.getAllJournalNames();
ListView journalNames = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.JournalList);
journalNames.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
journalNames.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Journal_Database>(
            this,R.layout.journal_name_list_black_text,R.id.list_content, values));
```

How could I set the CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE ?

I tried this:

```
 journalNames.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

But nothing happens.

**EDIT :**

I have found the solution, you can copy the choice_mode_multiple.xml file from the SDK folder to your project and change it.

I have this now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="15dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
android:paddingLeft="6dip"
android:paddingRight="6dip"
/>
```

And in the java code:

```
List<Journal_Database> values = localDatabase.getAllJournalNames();
    ListView journalNames = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.JournalList);
    journalNames.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Journal_Database>(
            this,R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,android.R.id.text1, values));
    journalNames.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

*Thank You*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this link.it may be Helpfull... http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Some Example like this...

```
public class MyList extends ListActivity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
    String[] names = new String[] { "Linux", "Windows7", "Eclipse", "Suse",
            "Ubuntu", "Solaris", "Android", "iPhone", "Linux", "Windows7",
            "Eclipse", "Suse", "Ubuntu", "Solaris", "Android", "iPhone" };
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
            android.R.id.text1, names));
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
}

}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I have fund the solution using the choice_mode_simple.xml from SDK, and then to modifie this a litle bit. I will post the solution.

Comment: Instead of copying that XML file you could have just used the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice`